# Quiero eliminar una tabla en una base de datos pero me muestra un error

Tags: base-de-datos

Al intentar hacer drop de una tabla me muestra un mensaje de error.

```
drop table "nombre de la tabla"
```

El error que me muestra es el siguiente:

> unique/primary keys in table referenced by foreign keys

Comment: Parece que tienes una llave foránea relacionada con otra tabla, antes de eliminar la tabla debes eliminar la llave foránea

Comment: Puedes agregar la etiqueta de la base de datos que usas para mayor precisión de las respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Es porque tiene relaciones a otras tablas. Debes eliminarlas o forzarlo.
Si estas en Oracle por ej.

```
DROP TABLE "nombre de la tabla" CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
```

Si no, deberías buscar como hacerlo en el motor que estés utilizando.

Saludos!